# Symfony6 - Exception: Could not find the entrypoints file from Webpack

Tags: symfony, webpack

I try to deploy my Symfony application to production.

I already ran the command:

```bash
yarn encore prod
```

I still see the following exception:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Could not find the entrypoints file from Webpack: the file "/home/mobil/public_html/public/build/entrypoints.json" does not exist.").

How can I resolve my issue?

Comment: did you try with "yarn encore prod"  ?

Comment: yes i tried @hous

Answer (score 1):

If i'ts a shared hosting, I think i'ts because the setPublicPath configuration.
I had a smillar problem before, the assets works in local but not on server and the solution was to make tow webpack configurations, on for local and the second for prod

https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/advanced-config.html#defining-multiple-webpack-configurations

```
Encore
// directory where compiled assets will be stored
.setOutputPath('public/build/')

.setPublicPath('/build')  // local config

.setManifestKeyPrefix('build/')

// ........

    })

;

const localConfig = Encore.getWebpackConfig();

localConfig.name = 'localConfig';
// reset Encore to build the second config
Encore.reset();


Encore
// directory where compiled assets will be stored
.setOutputPath('public/build/')

.setPublicPath('/public/build')  // for prod on shared hosting

.setManifestKeyPrefix('build/')

// .....

// build the second configuration
const prodConfig = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
// Set a unique name for the config (needed later!)
prodConfig.name = 'prodConfig';

// export the final configuration as an array of multiple configurations
module.exports = [localConfig, prodConfig];
```

the commands for each config:

```
./node_modules/.bin/encore dev --config-name localConfig

./node_modules/.bin/encore prod --config-name prodConfig
```

Comment: ok I was testing it tomorrow it's the end of the day I can't take it anymore @hous